# Capture the event of a sent email in outlook

Tags: c#, events, outlook, outlook-addin

i'm writing for a addin for Outlook and 
i'm trying to capture the event of a mail sent from outlook.
On thw web i've found a lot of examples for a SEND email, but i need to know the event of an email that was SENT.
There is a method or a procedure to hook this particular event?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use  `Application.ItemSend` event.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable which contains a boolean if a mail item is sent.
You can send your mail and check that boolean.

```
mailItem.Send();
if (mailItem.Sent) 
{
    // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My goal is to take the event of a sent email, but i cannot reach it because i don't know how to do. There is a sort of check/test to effectively try that i do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

i figured a simple cute work around for that, without using add-ins

Just check the MailItem.Sent value after displaying to user, if it's false than you know the email was closed without sending, and if it has no value, meaning you get an error "item was removed or deleted", that means the email was sent and that's why the object disappears

try it

```
MailItem.Display(True)

Try
     Dim sent As Boolean = MailItem.sent
     'msg was closed without sending
Catch ex As Exception
     'msg was sent
End Try
```

Comment: That will not work - message submission is an asynchronous process. The message will be sent and moved to the Sent Items folder much later (seconds or even minutes).

Comment: For me that worked well, when user closes the message without sending than i still have the object and the MailItem.sent value is false - but if user clicks Send, than i loose the object and the MailItem.sent doesn't exist anymore

Comment: The property exists just fine - it simply raises an exception because you are not allowed to do anything with a message being submitted. You are relying on behavior that can change with any Outlook update.